# Conformal invariance and phase transitions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, conformal-field-theory, critical-phenomena

At a second-order phase transition, a system exhibits fluctuations at any length scale. In such a scale-invariant regime, all the properties of the system follow specific scaling forms.
Close to a critical point, the system can be effectively described in terms of a conformal field theory.

Let us approach the problem from the opposite way. Suppose we have an action that, at low energies, enjoys invariance wrt scaling. In such a regime, the propagator follows a scaling behavior. My question is:

> Does a scaling form of the propagator necessarily imply the presence of a critical point?

Comment: Are you asking if every scale-invariant field model can be realized as a critical point in a non-scale-invariant context? Or are you asking if the form of the propagator in a given model is enough information to determine whether or not that model is scale-invariant?

Comment: I'm asking if an emergent conformal symmetry of a theory necessarily signals the presence of a critical point.